# Convert spherical to geographical coordinate system

Tags: math, three.js

I'm making a Globe in Three js and I'm having trouble converting Spherical coordinates (from Three's `Spherical` object) to geographical coordinates.

My current way of doing it is like so but I get some weird result (for Paris, FRANCE for example)

```
const lat = (phiAngle * (180 / Math.PI) - 90) * -1,
const lng = thetaAngle * (180 / Math.PI)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your approach looks reasonable. What are `phiAngle, thetaAngle` values  for Paris (should be near 0.7, 0.04) and what is weird result?

Comment: https://vvvv.org/blog/polar-spherical-and-geographic-coordinates

Comment: @MBo For example a `phi = 0.38613` it should give me `lat = 21,77` but with my current formula i get `lat = -68.22`

Comment: Do you start phi values from equator? In my mind, nothern pole is 0, lat 45N =  0.78, equator = 1.57 (Pi/2), south pole is 3.14 (Pi). Note range of `makeSafe () : Spherical` 0..Pi. Your formula gives +68.22  - according to this it is true

Comment: FWIW, Paris is at 0.71808779546, and your formula gives the correct value at 48.8566°N.